# Input shape in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, openai-gym

I am creating a deep neural network using Keras using images from the Gym library from Open AI.

I tried to reshape the images using the following code:

```
def reshape_dimensions(observation):
    processed = np.mean(observation,2,keepdims = False)
    cropped = processed[35:195]
    result = cropped[::2,::2]

    return result
```

This gives me an image of shape (80,80) but every time I try to input that shape in the first layer of the Keras network it doesn't work.

What should be the shape I should use so I can further develop the network?

Attached the whole code:

**PART I** retrieves the training data

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean, median
from collections import Counter


### GAME VARIABLE SETTINGS ###
env = gym.make('MsPacman-v0')
env.reset()

goal_steps = 2000
score_requirement = 250
initial_games = 200

print('Options to play: ',env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings())


### DEFINE FUNCTIONS ####

def reshape_dimensions(observation):
    processed = np.mean(observation,2,keepdims = False)
    cropped = processed[35:195]
    result = cropped[::2,::2]

    return result

def initial_population():
    training_data = []
    scores = []
    accepted_scores = []

    for _ in range(initial_games):
        score = 0
        game_memory = []
        prev_obvservation = []
        for _ in range(goal_steps):
            #env.render()
            action = env.action_space.sample() #Take random action in the env
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

            reshape_observation = reshape_dimensions(observation)

            if len(prev_obvservation) > 0:
                game_memory.append([prev_obvservation, action])

            prev_obvservation = reshape_observation

            score = score + reward
            if done: 
                break

        if score >= score_requirement:
            accepted_scores.append(score)

            for data in game_memory: 
                if data[1] == 0:
                    output = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 1:
                    output = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 2:
                    output = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 3:
                    output = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 4:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 5:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 6:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 7:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
                elif data[1] == 8:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

                training_data.append([data[0],output])



        env.reset()
        scores.append(score)


    print('Average accepted scores:', mean(accepted_scores))
    print('Median accepted scores:', median(accepted_scores))
    print(Counter(accepted_scores))

    return training_data 



### RUN CODE ###

training_data = initial_population()
np.save('data_for_training_200.npy', training_data)
```

**PART II** trains the model

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import keras
from statistics import mean, median
from collections import Counter
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam


### LOAD DATA ###

raw_training_data = np.load("data_for_training_200.npy")
training_data = [i[0:2] for i in raw_training_data]

print(np.shape(training_data))

### DEFINE FUNCTIONS ###


def neural_network_model():

    network = Sequential()
    network.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (80,80)))
    network.add(Dense(9,activation = 'softmax'))

    optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001)

    network.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return network

def train_model(training_data):

    X = [i[0] for i in training_data]
    y = [i[1] for i in training_data]

    #X = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data])
    #y = np.array([i[1] for i in training_data])

    print('shape of X: ', np.shape(X))
    print('shape of y: ', np.shape(y))

    early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience = 3)

    model = neural_network_model()

    model.fit(X, y, epochs = 20, callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor])

    return model

train_model(training_data = training_data)
```

Comment: Could you add the exact error you are getting to your question? What is the output in the terminal when you run your code?

Comment: attached the error code:
`ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 36859 arrays: [array([[150.        , 150.        ,  54.66666667, ...,  54.66666667,
        150.        , 150.        ],
       [150.        , 150.        ,  54.66666667, ...,  54.66666667,
        150.        , 15...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are pre-processing individual images correctly but putting them inside a list instead of an input tensor. From the error message you have a list of 36859 (80,80) arrays while you would like to have a single array of shape (36859, 80, 80). You have the code that does this commented out `X = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data])`, you have to ensure that every `i[0]` is of same shape (80,80) for this to work.